# Unity iOS Build - Wrong XCode Installation, Incorrect Clang Version

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, clang

Building a Unity 2022.1 project for iOS I get the following error:

```
Burst.Compiler.IL.Aot.AotLinkerException: XCode installation version is less than required. 
Clang version is 11.0.0 and 12.0.0 is the minimum required
```

This is weird because I have just updated XCode to 14.2 which apparently uses Clang 14.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out it was pointing to some old version. I probably previously installed it with brew, but now it is exclusively on the app store. I was able to fix it by entering this in the terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```